# log4net with ASP.NET MVC: nothing happens

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, log4net

I am trying to use log4net with ASP.NET MVC and I cannot get anything to happen with it.
I've created a config that is in my web project root:

```xml
<log4net>
    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender"/>
    </root>
    
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="C:\DWSApplicationFiles\AppLogs\app.log" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <rollingStyle value="Size" />
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
        <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
        <staticLogFileName value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%d [%t]%-5p %c [%x] - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="C:\DWSApplicationFiles\AppLogs\app.log" />
        <appendToFile value="false" />
        <datePattern value="-dddd" />
        <rollingStyle value="Date" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%d [%t]%-5p %c [%x] - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
</log4net>
```

Before I am asked: yes, the application has permission to write to the directory. I have tested this and the application has permission to this directory.

Here is where I am trying to use log4net:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        log.Error("In Index  ");
         return View();
    }
}
```

When I run the application and go to this controller log4net does nothing; it doesn't create the files in that directory or anything.

I have enabled internal debugging for log4net and I get no output errors in the console.
The following is all I see from log4net:

> log4net: log4net assembly [log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral,   PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821]. Loaded from [C:\Users\twaldron.BULLFROGSPAS\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7642c99a\60feb7f2\assembly\dl3\17247033\008dfd6d_e2d0ca01\log4net.DLL]. (.NET Runtime [2.0.50727.4952] on Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7600.0)
>
> log4net: DefaultRepositorySelector: defaultRepositoryType [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
>
> log4net: DefaultRepositorySelector: Creating repository for assembly [Bullfrog.DWS.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]
>
> log4net: DefaultRepositorySelector: Assembly [Bullfrog.DWS.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] Loaded From [C:\Users\twaldron.BULLFROGSPAS\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7642c99a\60feb7f2\assembly\dl3\2960c79f\b876bb2d_aca7cb01\Bullfrog.DWS.Web.DLL]
>
> log4net: DefaultRepositorySelector: Assembly [Bullfrog.DWS.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] does not have a RepositoryAttribute specified.
>
> log4net: DefaultRepositorySelector: Assembly [Bullfrog.DWS.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] using repository [log4net-default-repository] and repository type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
>
> log4net: DefaultRepositorySelector: Creating repository [log4net-default-repository] using type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
> 'WebDev.WebServer20.EXE' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'

Comment: Where's your Application_Start code calling  log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch ...?

Comment: Do you have `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>` before that configuration?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Do you have something like this in global.asax?

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string l4net = Server.MapPath("~/log4net.config");
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new System.IO.FileInfo(l4net));

    ...
```

Comment: nope I did not...I do now! And it works perfectly. I had no idea I needed that, though it makes sense now.Thank you for your help!

Comment: AndWatch I assume means that if the config file changes, it will immediately come into action in the application?

Comment: Yes, so you can tweak logging levels and such-like on the fly.

Answer (score 23):

Ensure that you call

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

At the startup of your application.

Answer (score 8):

## Confuguring Log4Net in ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application

1. Download Log4Net:

   - http://logging.apache.org/log4net/download.html
2. Add reference in ASP.Net MVC 4 application:

   1. Solution Explorer
   2. Right click on *project-name*
   3. Add references
   4. Browse *Log4Net.dll*
3. Modify *Web.config* file ([source](http://ideone.com/JRinYS)):

```xml
<configuration> 
    <configSections>
        <section
            name="log4net"
            type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    </configSections>
    <log4net>
        <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <param name="File" value="LOGS\log.txt"/>
            <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <rollingStyle value="Size" />
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
            <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
            <staticLogFileName value="true" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n"/>
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <root>
            <level value="ALL" />
            <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
        </root> 
        <logger name="test">
            <level value="DEBUG"></level>
        </logger>
    </log4net>
</configuration>
```

4. Modify *AssemblyInfo.cs*:

```cs
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Web.config", Watch = true)]
```

5. Modify *global.asax.cs*:

```cs
protected void Application_Start()
{
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Web.config")));
}
```

6. Add logger declaration in class for which you want to make logs:

```cs
readonly log4net.ILog log =
    log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(
        System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType
    );
```

7. Use log functions:

```cs
log.Error("make mistakes");
```

*Further reading: http://anandsonake.blogspot.in/2013/08/log4net-in-aspnet-mvc.html*

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Number 4 worked for me. I moved my solution from an empty ASP.NET solution to an ASP.NET web form, and without that line nothing was being logged.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in AssemblyInfo.cs :

> [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]